# Relationship between linear operators and linear functional in Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H=(H,(\cdot, \cdot))$ be a complex Hilbert space and $A:D(A)\subset H \longrightarrow H$ be a linear operator on $H$. I know there is a functional $ L: D(A) \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$, associated with $ A $ given by
$$L(u)=(A(u),u),\; \forall \; u \in D(A),$$ where $L$ is called the *quadratic form associated to $A$.*

> Is the converse true?

That is, given a functional $\mathcal{L}:D(\mathcal{L})\subset H \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$, then is there a linear operator $B: D(B) \subset H \longrightarrow H$ of $H$ associated with $\mathcal{L}$?

Comment: $L$ isn't linear.

Comment: @Aweygan Truth. Thanks, I'll fix it.

Comment: But now the "converse" is not really a converse.

Comment: Taking into account your and @Aweygan comment, I fixed the question.

Comment: What you may be trying to ask is the following:  if $\mathcal L:D(\mathcal L)\subset H\to\mathbb C$ is a quadratic form, is there an associated linear operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no.

For example, let $f$ be a functional that assigns $1$ to all of the vectors. Then we would like to have a linear operator $A$ with the property that
$$1=(Ax|x) \, \forall x \in H$$
which is absurd.

Comment: Under appropriate conditions, the converse is true?

Comment: @GuilhermedeLoreno What do you mean by "under appropriate conditions"?

Comment: Still in a general context, under some additional assumptions.

Comment: @GuilhermedeLoreno If we restrict ourselves to linear operators whose domain is the whole space, then we have that the topological dual "is the same" as the space itself (Riesz representation theorem), but the algebraic dual is much bigger. The space of functionals is even bigger, so I would doubt that you could find a similar connection to the Riesz representation theorem.

Comment: @GuilhermedeLoreno I think it's good to consider a really "small" example: on $\mathbb{C}^1$, you can represent all of the linear operators as multiplication by a complex number, and the inner product is just $(a|b)=a \overline{b}$. A functional is just a $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ function, so you would like to assign a constant $c$ to a functional $f$ so that $f(x)=(cx|x)=c|x|^2$.